# Akka Cluster Shard to Shard

Tags: akka, akka-cluster

I have a use case where one shard in a cluster needs to ask another shard in the same cluster for some information.

I know I could get the ShardRegion by doing something like this:

```
val counterRegion: ActorRef = ClusterSharding(system).shardRegion("Counter")
```

And then make my request like this:

```
counterRegion ? InfoRequest(entityIdShardId)
```

But, is there a way to get the shard region actor ref from the shard itself? That seems like it would be a cleaner and more efficient way to get the ActorRef.

Answer (score 0):

The way you specified is the correct way.

It is possible to call `context.parent` in shard entity and it returns `ActorRef` of the shard region. But this is less explicit option as it relies on fact that shard region is parent to shard entity.

I think you should keep using your option.

Additionally, unrelated to your question, you should not use ask pattern within actors. It adds more complexity of dealing with Future and requires a timeout specified. Just use send/tell or `!`. You can handle the response sent back to the actor in `receive` partial function.